# How to ensure execution after fixed amount of time in thread?

Tags: java

I have a problem regarding concurrency and scheduled execution. I am trying to implement my own threaded Clock (for fast-forward simulation purposes) which should increase a counter exactly every 5 seconds. Now I understand that threads can get blocked or are arbitrarily assigned execution time by the scheduler so I cannot guarantee that the counter gets increased every five seconds, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), here is an example:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTaskExample extends TimerTask {

    private volatile int counter;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start time:" + new Date());
        doSomeWork();
        System.out.println("End time:" + new Date());
    }


    private void doSomeWork() {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TimerTaskExample timerTask = new TimerTaskExample();
        // running timer task as daemon thread
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5 * 1000);
        System.out.println("TimerTask begins! :" + new Date());
        // cancel after sometime
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("TimerTask cancelled! :" + new Date());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

About accuracy, read the Javadoc of the `schedule` method you are using. I don't thing you can get absolute precision, no matter what you are using.

Comment: I think `counter` should be declared `volatile`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Definitely, but this as just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to ensure the counter will be incremented after *exactly* 5 seconds.

If you use a `ScheduledExecutorService`, it can guarantee that your counter will be incremented *sometime* after 5 seconds (but not sooner).

```
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.schedule(() -> counter.incrementAndGet(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```